# How to extract a timestamp using a regex

Tags: ruby, regex, fluentd

I need to extract the time stamp from `[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]`.

For example, matching:

```
[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]
```

should extract:

```
02/24/2016 03:37:27.996
```

This returns the date and time separately:

```
\[(?<date>[^\]]*)\]\[(?<time>[^\]]*)\]
```

This is the Rubular [example](http://rubular.com/r/jxJQghzeGu) for your easy reference.

I'm looking for how to combine these two groups, date and time, into a timestamp.

Comment: That is either achieved with replacing the unnecessary text or using some code to concatenate the two group contents. You can't just use a single regex pattern to *match* two non-adjoining text parts.

Comment: is there no way to achieve from only regex?

Comment: [some placeholder text since you can't just write...] No.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to format your question for readability when asking. Stack Overflow is an online reference book, and readability, grammar and spelling, do matter, both for us trying to help you and for those in the future looking for solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a pattern to extract the information as one result or string because of the way that regular expressions work. You'll either get two captures:

```
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/).captures # => ["02/24/2016", "03:37:27.996"]
```

which you could use like:

```
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.match(/\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]/).captures.join(' ') # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
```

or one capture containing the intervening `"[]"` characters:

```
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.match(/\[([^\]]+\]\[[^\]]+)\]/).captures # => ["02/24/2016][03:37:27.996"]
```

You can do it other ways though:

```
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'[1..-2].sub('][', ' ') # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
```

which, using a simple slice and `sub`, is how I'd do it, or:

```
[[1, 10], [13, 12]].map {|s, l| '[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'[s, l] }.join(' ') # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.tr('[]', ' ').strip.squeeze(' ') # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.gsub(/[\[\]]+/, ' ').strip # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
'[02/24/2016][03:37:27.996]'.scan(/[\d\/:.]+/).join(' ') # => "02/24/2016 03:37:27.996"
```

When people learn about regular expressions everything looks like the perfect opportunity to use them, everything is the chance to hit the problem with the regular expression hammer. Unfortunately that's not close to the truth. They're powerful, but when used improperly they can slow your code, they can introduce very subtle bugs and logic holes, and they can make your code much harder to debug because, as they get more complex they also get more convoluted. Keep them simple for sanity, or learn how to generate them using code that assembles them for you.